# How can I remove CMakeCache.txt during CMake configuration if it has outdated info?

Tags: c++, cmake, cmakelists-options

My CMakeLists.txt uses `CheckSymbolExists` to determine which definitions for __NR_xyz syscall numbers are missing in `asm/unistd.h`. And previously it looked in `unistd.h` instead, which resulted in inaccurate HAVE_NR_XYZ definitions being stored in CMakeCache.txt.

I can clean the old incorrect HAVE_NR_XYZ definitions manually by removing CMakeCache.txt, but others will still do incremental builds using the updated CMakeLists.txt that checks `asm/unistd.h`, and use the old existing CMakeCache.txt.

Can I remove CMakeCache.txt programmatically from CMakeLists.txt if it doesn't contain some definition (like HAVE_NR_XYZ, or something else defined for this purpose)?

Or is there another way I can specify in CMakeLists.txt to delete old CMakeCache.txt files, but only if they were generated before the `asm/unistd.h` fix went in?

Comment: Currently I am programmatically grepping from CMakeLists.txt in CMakeCache.txt for `HAVE_NR_BIND` which apparently all toolchains have, but the old CMakeLists check evaluated to "false". And if grep finds an empty `HAVE_NR_BIND=`, I print an error prompting the dev to remove their CMakeCache.txt. But hopefully there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to want to delete the entire cache file in a CMake project configuration file. The whole point of the cache... is to be a cache. And if I understand correctly, the cache is loaded near the start of the configuration phase, so even if you programmatically deleted it with a command in the CMake configuration, you'd still need to run configuration again to see the effect. I.e. It's not something you can "chop off" during configuration and then the variables it set will all magically be unset. CMake reads that file and sets the variables, and if you want them unset, you need to manually unset each one.

If you want to run with a fresh cache, you can and should do so from the invocation of the configure command. In CMake 3.24 and up, you can run with a fresh cache using [`--fresh`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-fresh) in the configuration command. From its docs:

> Perform a fresh configuration of the build tree. This removes any existing CMakeCache.txt file and associated CMakeFiles/ directory, and recreates them from scratch.

If you want to do fine-grained editing of the variable cache, you can use [`-U <globbing expr>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-U), or use an interactive cache-editing applications. CMake comes with two such interactive dialogs: [ccmake, and cmake-gui](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/#interactive-dialogs). Make sure to run configuration again after editing the cache. The interactive dialogs have buttons / keybindings to do so, and `cmake --build` may actually be smart enough to detect that re-configuration needs to happen. Your IDE might also provide a CMake cache-editing GUI (though the quality may not be as good as the CMake-provided ones).

Answer (score 1):

Run cmake with `-U HAVE_NR_XYZ`. This will reset `HAVE_NR_XYZ` in CMakeCache.txt.

Comment: Would this work for unsuspecting devs doing git pull, and building in an existing dir for incremental benefits ?

Comment: I don't understand what use case you mean in the comment.

Comment: I updated the CheckSymbolExists calls today to correctly look in `asm/unistd.h`, since previously all of them would fail to find any __NR_xyz definition in `unistd.h`. But pushing this CMakeLists.txt fix to the upstream repo won't change anything for other people who pull the fix, since they will be using the cached HAVE_NR_XYZ values in their existing CMakeCache.txt, and all of them will still incorrectly appear to be missing.

Comment: You are right. All of your project users should run cmake with `-U`. It will work for them if it works for you.